# python editor/IDE that shows available functions and more importantly their documentation

Tags: python, ide

```
f = open(filename, 'r')
strings = f.read().lower()
```

I want a python editor/ide  that works like visual studio. In the above after typing 'f.' it shows me the list of available functions and their documentation(DO NOT WAIT FOR ctrl-space). Just like visual express C#. Also preferably it shows autocomplete lists of all variables as well. Is there such an editor?

I have gone through several suggestions - eclipse , vim , emacs , pyscripter, komodo etc etc. Tired of trying. finally asking. 
Help me out.

I have checked similar questions, none answered my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Netbeans. It is free. Some of its features -

- It shows a list of functions and their documentations as well as variables `but on Ctrl+Space`. (I don't know why you don't want to hit Ctrl+Space, otherwise every time you start writing something, you will be disturbed by a popup.)
- It also underlines unused variables, plus the other usual things like syntax highlighting, matching closing brackets, etc.
- You can easily change the name of variables within a function/class using the refractor.
- You can find usages of a particular names within your project
- You can view all your classes, their methods and attributes, functions and global variables at a glance using the navigator.
- It has a project manager
- You can debug your project.
- (whatever else you can possibly think of.)

It has lots of other features... I can't name them all here.

It is the best opensource IDE !

Comment: just tried netbeans and it has exactly what I need. automatic code completion with docs. finally! Note: Use netbeans 6.9 for python. netbeans 7 doesn't have python support

Comment: ya.. sorry I forgot to mention that!

Answer (score 4):

Try to take a look at PyCharm. It not open source but it is quite cheap and powerful IDE:

http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/
http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/index.html

> Code completion for keywords, classes,
>   variables, etc. — Ctrl+Space. Editor
>   suggestions are context-aware and
>   suggest most appropriate options.
>
> Quick definition / documentation view
>   — see the object definition or
>   documentation in-place without losing
>   your context

Comment: I can't seem to find the documentation view. help?

Comment: If you have already downloaded PyCharm evaluation version than you need to open help and look there for 'viewing inline documentation' topic. I am not using this feature but seems that all that you need is to select method, class and etc. and then 'Ctrl+Q'. Also you can configure code completion to show you documentation automatically - see 'settings->editor->code completion'

Comment: Unfortunately pycharm ain't smart enough...fopen = open(filename, 'r')...  filestring = fopen.read()....  filestring (NO POPUP)

Comment: I guess that PyCharm is smart, the issue here is that it couldn't know what output is. Change your code to lines = fopen.readlines() and then type lines. and you will see what i mean

Comment: you are right. its not that it isn't smart, its just that it can't detect the var type. so it can't provide completion..

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that [wingide](http://www.wingware.com/) code completion works like that. I tried the example you have here and it worked

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I'll try this now

Comment: Is there a particular setting for this? Coz I just tried and nothing popped up on pressing '.' It did complete the variable name though

Comment: @user, I think it's the default setting. When I type `f` it does variable completion, then when i type `.` it shows the file methods. Which version are you using?

Comment: hmm its working for some vars, for others it gives a cannot determine filetype error in the document view...But its pretty buggy and laggy, so I'll give this a pass

Answer (score 1):

I use Pydev, after Vim it speeds a lot! You can quickly navigate your project tree, in tabs you open necessary files, also inline watching of class/method definition, you can even 'jump' to that file. Also you can mark project as 'Django project', after setting python paths it really helps make less mistakes and code quickly. Also I've very much benefited multi-file search/replace. Recommend it! :)

Note: If you use Linux, replase OpenJRE with binary from Oracle's site. Otherwise there'll be craches.